# In .NET, Is GC.MaxGeneration Ever Not 2?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

As far as I understand it, there are three generations of garbage collection - 0, 1 and 2, for all versions of .NET.

Are there any circumstances where examining `GC.MaxGeneration` would yield anything other than 2? Are there GCs on other frameworks that have a different number of GC generations?

Comment: I haven't tested, but the old Compact Framework used a non-generational GC, and `MaxGeneration` is documented to return 0 in this case, so perhaps in CF?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It should be noted that [GC.MaxGeneration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.maxgeneration.aspx) being constant for the application's lifetime is in itself an implementation detail:

> **Notes to Implementers**
>
> For this implementation, the value returned by the `MaxGeneration`
>   property is guaranteed to remain constant for the lifetime of an
>   executing application.

This implies that not only can `MaxGeneration` be different from `2` in other implementations of the .NET framework, but it can also *vary* during program execution (depending on the number of generations used by the garbage collector at the time the property getter is called).

Other implementations can also use different garbage collectors depending on the circumstances. For instance, Mono can either use the [Boehm non-generational GC](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono%3aRuntime#Mono.27s_use_of_Boehm_GC) (`MaxGeneration` will always be `0` then), or the [SGen generational GC](http://www.mono-project.com/Generational_GC) (which only implements two generations, so `MaxGeneration` will always be less than or equal to `1` there).

Comment: I don't understand. It says _..guaranteed to remain constant for the lifetime of an executing application.._, yet you say it may _..vary during program execution.._.

Comment: @John, because it says *for this implementation*. In other words, `MaxGeneration` remaining constant only applies to Microsoft's implementation of the .NET framework.

Comment: In the SSCLI, it's hardcoded to return 2, so I doubt it's going to change during execution.

Comment: I understand, but during a single execution of an application, I think it can never change. Maybe I'm mistaken, but I don't think different implementations will be used during application execution.

Comment: @John, the implementation of .NET that is used by an application indeed won't change during its lifetime, but the point is that `MaxGeneration` can vary during program execution if another implementation than Microsoft's is used.